# facebook developer toolkit - RequiredPermissions not working

Tags: c#, facebook

I am using facebook developer toolkit along with c#.

I would like to require my users to allow me offline and email access. I am using the following code, but it does nothing...

```
RequiredPermissions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions>();
RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.email);
RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.offline_access);
RequireLogin = true;
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Canvas (FBML or Iframe), you must put your code in the constructor of your page. Then Facebook will redirect you to get permissions page. Saludos